# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() Stack trace: #0 {main}

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Using PHP 8, installed PHP Driver in **C:\xampp\php\ext** directory and added

- `extension_dir=C:\xampp\php\ext`
- `extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll`
- `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll`
  in **php.ini** file. However, I am still getting the above error on `sqlsrv_connect` below

```
$serverName = "(local)";  
$connectionInfo = array ("UID"=>"xx","PWD"=>"xxxxxxx","Database"=>"xxxx");  
$conn = sqlsrv_connect ($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

All I need was to update the path for PHP 8, previously it was looking at the wrong PHP version.